# How do I add the TcpClient parameter to the DataReceived event handler SimpleTCP?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am confused how to add parameters to the DataReceived SimpleTCP event handler.

Here's my coding:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        server = new SimpleTcpServer();
        server.Delimiter = 0x13; //Enter
        server.StringEncoder = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
        server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;
        server.ClientConnected += Server_ClientConnected;
        server.ClientDisconnected += Server_ClientDisconnected;
    }
```

Call Event Handler DataReceived

```
server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;
```

And this code function Server_DataReceived

```
private void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e, TcpClient client)
    {

        listView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
        {
            string json = e.MessageString.Remove(e.MessageString.Length - 1);
            S3Object s3obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<S3Object>(json);
            ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(s3obj.id);
            lv.SubItems.Add(s3obj.bucket);
            lv.SubItems.Add(s3obj.objects);
            listView1.Items.Add(lv);
        });

    }
```

I have error in this
[Error on server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD2j1.png)

Thanks guys

Comment: Data received seems to have 2 parameters only sender and message you cant just force client into there..

Comment: Why do you need a "client" when you implement a server?  Do note that parameter doesn't get used anywhere in the snippet.  If necessary make it a member of the class or use a lambda expression that captures the variable.

Comment: I need client info connected to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use the [SimpleTCP](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleTCP/) Library by BrandonPotter.
Please add information about used 3rd party libraries in your Question, as it makes it a lot easier for others to help.

The Message object passed in the `DataReceived` and `DelimiterDataReceived` event contains a property `TcpClient` that is the information you need. Therefore you need no additional parameter.

I think you would better use `DelimiterDataReceived`, therefore your code would look like this:

```
private void Server_DelimiterReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e, TcpClient client)
{
    listView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
    {
        string json = e.MessageString;
        S3Object s3obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<S3Object>(json);
        ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(s3obj.id);
        lv.SubItems.Add(s3obj.bucket);
        lv.SubItems.Add(s3obj.objects);
        listView1.Items.Add(lv);

        TcpClient client = e.TcpClient;
        // do something with the client...
    });
}
```